# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start, fsevents, npm-live-server

**When trying to run npm start, I'm receiving two errors**

1. dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate
2. dyld: Symbol not found: _FSEventStreamCreate

[image]

This happens in every local repository on my machine, except one.

What seemed to get that repo to work was removing unused header files via brew, and restarting the computer.

However, the error persists in every other repository.

**Here are the details:**

Using a 2015 Macbook Pro 15 inch, running MacOS Mojave version 10.14.6

- Node Version - v10.20.1
- NPM Version - 6.14.5

**So far, we've tried:**

- Looking for software updates via Mac App Store - None are pending for my comp.
- Check the package.json to see if the dependencies are
  the same (they are) (screenshot attached)
- Updating command line tools to 11.3
- Different versions of node - 14, 10, 12
- Uninstalling & re-installing node modules - Before & After installing CLT & Rebooting
- installing fs_events globally
- installing live server globally
- removing unused header files

**I've made sure the dependencies are the same**

[image]

[image]

I'm definitely missing something, so any help is greatly appreciated!

**Update**
Switching to Node version 14 seems to work, however after restarting it fails. Switching to a different version of node and then back seems to work as a temp fix